# Query with elements depended on another

Tags: sql, postgresql

There is a Postgres database and the table has three columns.  The data structure is in external system so I can not modify it.

Every object is represented by three rows (identified by column `element_id` - rows with the same value in this column represents the same object), for example:

```
key     value            element_id
-----------------------------------
status  active           1
name    exampleNameAAA   1
city    exampleCityAAA   1
status  inactive         2
name    exampleNameBBB   2
city    exampleCityBBB   2
status  inactive         3
name    exampleNameCCC   3
city    exampleCityCCC   3
```

In the query, I want to put list of some names, check if the value of row with `key` column `status` in the same object has status 'active' and return the name of this objects only if the status is 'active'.

So for this example, there are three objects in the database table.  I want to put in query two 'names':

a)`exampleNameAAA`

b)`exampleNameCCC`

and the result should be:
`exampleNameAAA` (because I asked for two objects and only one of them has `active` value in `status` row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an EXISTS query:

```
select e1.*
from element e1
where (e1.key, e1.value)  in ( ('name', 'exampleNameAAA'), ('name', 'exampleNameCCC'))
and exists (select *
            from element e2
            where e2.element_id = e1.element_Id  
              and (e2.key, e2.value) = ('status', 'active'));
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/JOWED21150

Answer (score 0):

One option uses aggregation:

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN "key" = 'name' THEN "value" END) AS name
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY element_id
HAVING
    MAX(CASE WHEN "key" = 'name' THEN "value" END) IN
        ('exampleNameAAA', 'exampleNameCCC') AND
    SUM(CASE WHEN "key" = 'status' AND "value" = 'active' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0;

name
exampleNameAAA
```

### Demo

This is the pivot approach, where we isolate individual keys and values for each `element_id` group.

Answer (score 0):

I like expressing this as:

```
SELECT MAX(t.value) FILTER (WHERE t.key = 'name') AS name
FROM t
GROUP BY t.element_id
HAVING MAX(t.value) FILTER (WHERE t.key = 'name') IN ('exampleNameAAA', 'exampleNameCCC') AND
       MAX(t.value) FILTER (WHERE t.key = 'status') = 'active';
```

All that said, the `exists` solution is probably more performant in this case.  The advantage of the aggregation approach is that you can easily bring additional columns into the `select`, such as the city:

```
SELECT MAX(t.value) FILTER (WHERE t.key = 'name') AS name,
       MAX(t.value) FILTER (WHERE t.key = 'city') as city
```

(Note:  `key` is a bad name for a column because it is a SQL keyword.)

Comment: This looks very similar to my query.  Was it worth posting this, given that the performance would be identical to what I wrote an hour earlier?